# why python spark slow when use for loop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning pyspark from write a page rank program.
But when I use for loop to compute, every iteration is getting slower.
I try to use cache, but it seems don't work.
I have no idea how to fix this problem.
[image: performance]

Here is my loop code

```py
from time import time
for idx, i in tqdm(enumerate(range(10))):

    start_time = time() # <-- start timing

    new_values = stochastic_matrix.flatMap(lambda x: get_new_value(x, beta, N))
    new_values = new_values.reduceByKey(add).map(lambda x: [x[0], x[1] + ((1-beta)/N)] )
    S = new_values.values().reduce(add)
    new_stochastic_matrix = stochastic_matrix.fullOuterJoin(new_values)
    stochastic_matrix = new_stochastic_matrix.map(lambda x: sum_new_value(x, S, N))

    new_stochastic_matrix.cache()
    stochastic_matrix.cache() # <--- cache here


    end_time = time()
    print(idx, end_time - start_time)

sorted(stochastic_matrix.collect())[:10]
```

## Update

After I comment this line

```
stochastic_matrix = new_stochastic_matrix.map(lambda x: sum_new_value(x, S, N))
```

It work normal !!
But I still don't know why and how to fix it.

## Update 2

I set S as a constant, the speed is normal.
But I still don't know why and how to fix it.

## All Flow

### After Input Data

variable: stochastic_matrix - data struct looks like this.

```py
[
(key,[value, this_node_connect_to_which_node]),
(1, [0.2, [2, 3]]),
(2, [0.2, [4]]),
(3, [0.2, [1, 4, 5]]),
(4, [0.2, []]),
(5, [0.2, [1, 4]])
]
```

### Map

```py
def get_new_value(item, beta, N):
    key, tmp = item
    value, dest = tmp
    N_dest = len(dest)

    new_values = []
    for i in dest:
        new_values.append([i, beta * (value/ N_dest)] )

    return new_values

new_values = stochastic_matrix.flatMap(lambda x: get_new_value(x, beta, N))
new_values.collect()

########### output
[node, each_node_new_value]
[[2, 0.08000000000000002],
 [3, 0.08000000000000002],
 [4, 0.16000000000000003],
 [1, 0.05333333333333334],
 [4, 0.05333333333333334],
 [5, 0.05333333333333334],
 [1, 0.08000000000000002],
 [4, 0.08000000000000002]]
```

### Reduce by key

beta and N is just a float number

```py
new_values = new_values.reduceByKey(add).map(lambda x: [x[0], x[1] + ((1-beta)/N)] )
new_values.collect()

###### Output
[[2, 0.12000000000000001],
 [3, 0.12000000000000001],
 [4, 0.33333333333333337],
 [1, 0.17333333333333334],
 [5, 0.09333333333333332]]
```

### Combine new_values and stochastic_matrix

```py
new_stochastic_matrix = stochastic_matrix.fullOuterJoin(new_values)
new_stochastic_matrix.collect()

#### Output
# (key, ([value, this_node_connect_to_which_node], new_value))

[(2, ([0.2, [4]], 0.12000000000000001)),
 (4, ([0.2, []], 0.33333333333333337)),
 (1, ([0.2, [2, 3]], 0.17333333333333334)),
 (3, ([0.2, [1, 4, 5]], 0.12000000000000001)),
 (5, ([0.2, [1, 4]], 0.09333333333333332))]
```

### Update new_value to value

S and N are just a number

```py
def sum_new_value(item, S, N):
    key, value = item

    if value[1] == None:
        new_value = 0 + (1-S)/N
    else:
        new_value = value[1] + (1-S)/N


#     new_value = value[1]

    return [key, [new_value, value[0][1]]]

stochastic_matrix = new_stochastic_matrix.map(lambda x: sum_new_value(x, S, N))

sorted(stochastic_matrix.collect())[:10]

######## Output
[[1, [0.2053333333333333, [2, 3]]],
 [2, [0.152, [4]]],
 [3, [0.152, [1, 4, 5]]],
 [4, [0.36533333333333334, []]],
 [5, [0.1253333333333333, [1, 4]]]]
```

Comment: can you provide the functions and variables you have used for example, `stochastic_matrix`, `get_new_value`, `beta`, `N`

Comment: @ClockSlave Tanks, I update more information.